# Dlookup on textbox is not working

Tags: ms-access, textbox

I have been researching on MS-Access topics around DLookup, but not being lucky on the resolution of my problem.

I have a query that solely returns one value, which is a lumpsum of credits. So I used the clause "AS TOT_CREDIT" on the query to give the unique column a name.

On access report, I learned that you can't directly set the value of a textbox from a query, but also learned the magic is to set the textbox controlsource property to dlookup, like this: `dlookup([TOT_CREDIT]; [QUERY THAT CONTAINS TOT_CREDIT])`. When I pull the report from access, the textbox still displays the infamous "#Name?", instead of the query value.

Is anything missing here? What else can I do in order to have the textbox display the query result?

Answer (score 0):

Must use quotation marks:

`DLookup("[TOT_CREDIT]"; "[QUERY THAT CONTAINS TOT_CREDIT]")`.